# How to push string in a given range in stack in C++?

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    istringstream iss(dtr);
    Stack <string> mudassir;
    mudassir.push1(s1);
    string subs;
    do {
        iss >> subs;
        if (subs == "|post_exp|")
        {
            iss >> subs;
            while (subs != "|\\post_exp|")
            {
                mudassir.push(subs);
                cout << "heloo";
                iss >> subs;
            }
        }
    } while (iss);
}
```

I want to push a certain element of string in stack. But the problem is in this code, the inner `while` loop which has `hello` (just for testing) in it is running infinitely. I don't know why.

Comment: Use `std::string::find` to determine the position of the text you want to extract.  Use `std::substr()` to extract the text from your string.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews In this problem i have to extract the string inside tags and store it into another variable. I don't think the method you suggested is gonna work

Comment: @MudassirWaheed yes, it will.  You can `find()` the starting substring you are interested in (ie, `"|post_exp|"`), then `find()` the next ending substring (ie, `"|\\post_exp|"`), and then `substr()` everything that is between those two positions. Repeat until no more matches are found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the inner `while` loop which has `hello` (just for testing) in it is running infinitely. I don't know why.

Your inner `while` loop is not taking into account when the stream reaches the end of its data.

When `operator>>` reaches the end of the stream, it will put the stream into the `eofbit` state, and `subs` will be set to whatever data was left in the stream. Subsequent reads with `operator>>` will put the stream into the `failbit` state, and set `subs` to a blank value.

Your inner loop is ignoring the stream's state completely, and the blank value satisfies the `!=` condition that you are checking.  That is why your loop runs forever.

You need to pay attention to the stream's state. For example:

```
int main()
{
    istringstream iss(dtr);
    Stack <string> mudassir;
    mudassir.push1(s1);
    string subs;
    while (iss >> subs) {
        if (subs == "|post_exp|")
        {
            while (iss >> subs && subs != "|\\post_exp|")
            {
                mudassir.push(subs);
                cout << "heloo";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you provided push all the element in stack rather then elements present inside opening and closing tag kindly check so that it only push those strings in stack which are inside tags e.g |post_exp| this is tag

Comment: Works fine for me: https://ideone.com/rpUHUY

Comment: Can you please implement stack of your on rather using from library because it gives error in visual studio